# I Want to remove the video if free_preview: false in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, api, express

if its free_preview is true means, the video data must preview to all and when the free_preview is false means its not might expose the video data.

But in this scenario if free_preview is false then also the video data is expose.

i want to make this to  preview the videos wheather the free_preview is true otherwise the videos doesn't expose.

how can i solve this?

-----------------API CODE--------------------

```
export const courses = async (req, res) => {
              const all = await Course.find({ published: true})
                .populate("instructor", "_id name")
                .exec();
              res.json(all)
            };
```

```
 import { json } from "express";
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
    const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const lessonSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 320,
          required: true,
        },
        slug: {
          type: String,
          lowercase: true,
        },
        content: {
          type: String,
          minlength: 200,
        },
        video: {},
        time:{
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
          min: 1,
          max: 5
        },
        free_preview: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    
    const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 320,
          required: true,
        },
        slug: {
          type: String,
          lowercase: true,
        },
        description: {
          type: {},
          minlength: 200,
          required: true,
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          default: 500,
        },
        image: {},
        category: String,
        published: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        paid: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true,
        },
        instructor: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
          required: true,
        },
        Category:{
          type : String,
          trim: true,
          min: 4,
          max: 200
        },
        lessons: [lessonSchema],
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    export default mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);
```

```
----------------------------api response ----------------------------------
```

```
    [
        {
            "price": 400,
            "published": true,
            "paid": true,
            "_id": "61d73468f0ef1c2df856d580",
            "slug": "nmap-for-ethical-hacking",
            "instructor": {
                "_id": "61d73336f0ef1c2df856d57f",
                "name": "lenin royal"
            },
            "name": "Nmap for ethical hacking",
            "description": "sfdsfdf",
            "lessons": [
                {
                    "free_preview": false,
                    "_id": "61d73721da89b03378321bc3",
                    "title": "intro",
                    "content": "sdfdfdff",
                    "video": {
                        "Location": "https://berrys01.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/_k8b_Khyz9GgTZkomm7WS.mp4",
                        "Bucket": "berrys01",
                        "Key": "_k8b_Khyz9GgTZkomm7WS.mp4",
                        "ETag": "\"00bf0fea24f997ac205c16de2ca3f7fa-2\""
                    },
                    "slug": "intro",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T18:38:25.674Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-06T18:38:25.674Z"
                },
                {
                    "free_preview": true,
                    "_id": "61d737b8da89b03378321bc4",
                    "title": "hgdsfhgsdf",
                    "content": "dfsdfdf",
                    "video": {
                        "Location": "https://berrys01.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Nqc6YL5LG1r3kWZIPigc1.mp4",
                        "Bucket": "berrys01",
                        "Key": "Nqc6YL5LG1r3kWZIPigc1.mp4",
                        "ETag": "\"4fbfb64ae636171fa7a7020ecc3b6a9e-16\""
                    },
                    "slug": "hgdsfhgsdf",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T18:40:56.963Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-06T18:40:56.963Z"
                },
                {
                    "free_preview": true,
                    "_id": "61d737cada89b03378321bc5",
                    "title": "hello",
                    "content": "dfgdfg",
                    "video": {
                        "Location": "https://berrys01.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/fv5jEXzphsJ9al9DMKAr3.mp4",
                        "Bucket": "berrys01",
                        "Key": "fv5jEXzphsJ9al9DMKAr3.mp4",
                        "ETag": "\"72e0076dec633d7f3630628e92ba1891-3\""
                    },
                    "slug": "hello",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:14.132Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:14.132Z"
                },
                {
                    "free_preview": true,
                    "_id": "61d737d6da89b03378321bc6",
                    "title": "rgrg",
                    "content": "dgdf",
                    "video": {
                        "Location": "https://berrys01.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/gmYnDGSrspH4jgfhC8ybr.mp4",
                        "Bucket": "berrys01",
                        "Key": "gmYnDGSrspH4jgfhC8ybr.mp4",
                        "ETag": "\"72e0076dec633d7f3630628e92ba1891-3\""
                    },
                    "slug": "rgrg",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:26.610Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:26.610Z"
                },
                {
                    "free_preview": true,
                    "_id": "61d737e2da89b03378321bc7",
                    "title": "rgdgry56t5",
                    "content": "5yr",
                    "video": {
                        "Location": "https://berrys01.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/hzRW7TJn9ichITOk-3A-w.mp4",
                        "Bucket": "berrys01",
                        "Key": "hzRW7TJn9ichITOk-3A-w.mp4",
                        "ETag": "\"72e0076dec633d7f3630628e92ba1891-3\""
                    },
                    "slug": "rgdgry56t5",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:38.985Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-06T18:41:38.985Z"
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, a solution would be to do something like this

```
const courses = await Course
  .find({ published: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'lessons',
    match: { free_preview: true },
    select: 'name -_id'
  })
  .exec();
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply but your code actually not working because lessons is an object so please give the alternative solution.

Comment: I think that you need to register your relation as follow instead


mongoose.model("Lesson", lessonSchema)
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    lessons: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Lesson' }]
})

If you want to keel the lessons as un object, I think that you might need to filter the result later